# Log aspect in PostSharp 5.0.23 not applied at assembly level

Tags: postsharp

I am following the steps mentioned in http://doc.postsharp.net/add-logging . The Visual studio version is 2017 and PostSharp 5.0.28 extension is installed. When the log aspect for console backend is added to the whole project, the GlobalAspect.cs file is added but the output shows no log trace. But when I apply the [Log] attribute to the method the log trace is seen. Why is the definition in GlobalAspect not applied?

```
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;    
namespace ConsoleApp1    
{    
    [Log(AttributeExclude = true)]    
    public class Program    
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)    
        {                 
            LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Backends.Console.ConsoleLoggingBackend();
        }            
        public static void f()    
        {    
        }    
    }    
}
```

I have the following entry in GlobalAspects.cs file of console and dll. While in dll it works, the console it doesn't.

```
[assembly: Log(AttributeTargetTypeAttributes=MulticastAttributes.Public‌​, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes=MulticastAttributes.Public)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GlobalAspect seems to have no impact on Console application. On a class library, it does work neat.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the `[Log]` aspect on the assembly level, it is propagated to the methods in the assembly according to the specified rules.

You can set properties such `AttributeTargetTypeAttributes`, `AttributeTargetMemberAttributes` to specify whether you want to target public,private, instance, static methods etc. You can also specify the namespace, type and member names.

The defaults for these properties may not correspond with what you want. You need to make sure that the specified properties match the characteristics of the desired target methods.

```
[Log(AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.AnyVisibility)]
```

You can find more details on this documentation page: http://doc.postsharp.net/attribute-multicasting